# Reading XML file with header and footer in spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm writing a batch job for reading XML file with a header and footer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Hdr>
    <hdrField1>1644</hdrField1>
    <hdrField2>670</hdrField2>
    <hdrField3>00000001</hdrField3>
  </Hdr>
  <TxnBlock>
    <Txn>
        <txnField1>1644</txnField1>
        <txnField2>670</txnField2>
        <txnField3>00000001</txnField3>
    </Txn>
    <Txn>
    ...............
    </Txn>
    <Txn>
    ...............
    </Txn>
  </TxnBlock>
  <Trl>
    <trlField1>1644</trlField1>
    <trlField2>670</trlField2>
    <trlField3>00000001</trlField3>
  </Trl>
</File>
```

I'm using `Jaxb2Marshaller`

```
@StepScope
    public StaxEventItemReader<XmlVo> xmlReader()
            throws MalformedURLException {

        String fileName="011SBIN00200011924701.xml";
        StaxEventItemReader<XmlVo> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[] { "File","Hdr","Trl","Txn" });
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(XmlVo.class,
                 HeaderVo.class,FooterVo.class,TxnVo.class);
        reader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

        return reader;
    }


@XmlRootElement(name = "File")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlVo {        

      @XmlElement(name="Hdr") 
      private HeaderVo Hdr;

      @XmlElement(name="Trl") 
      private FooterVo Trl;

      @XmlElement(name="TxnBlock") 
      private TxnBlockVo TxnBlock;

      /*@XmlElement(name="Txn") //
       private List<TxnVo> txn;*/


//getter setter
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "TxnBlock")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TxnBlockVo {

    @XmlElement(name="Txn") //
    private List<TxnVo> txn;

   //getter setter
}
```

I'm able to read data from file. 
The issue is I'm not getting the records in chunk. My chunk size is 5 and file contain nearly 1000 Txn fragments, But the whole file is reading as one.

I tried put `List<TxnVo>` in the `XmlVo.class`. But nullpoint Exception occur in processor when i try to read value from Txn list.

When reading  Txn fragment only, processing is perfect. But i need to read header and footer also.

Is my processing is correct?  
How to implement batch processing in xml file with header and footer records?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What defines an item in your case? According to your `XmlVo`, it is a header + footer + Txn fragment. And this is for every item.. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. My file have one header, one footer and many Txns.  inside `TxnBlockVo ` i give a list of  `TxnVo` to read the txn fragment. I'm not sure whether this item structure is correct or not.

Comment: Indeed, you would probably need to update your structure/mapping. I added an answer with more details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the `StaxEventItemReader` is designed to work. A single XML fragment (which can be as complex as you want) is assumed to correspond to an item. Here is an excerpt from the [XML Item Readers and Writers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#xmlReadingWriting) section of the reference documentation:

> it is assumed an XML resource is a collection of 'fragments' corresponding to individual records

In your case, for each record, you want to map an item from a header (start of the file) + a fragment (somewhere in the middle of the file) + a footer (end of file). This requires the reader to go back and forth in the input file which does not conform to the contract of an item reader to be forward only as explained in the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemReader):

> It is expected that implementations of the ItemReader interface are forward only.

So in your case, you need to update your mapping to conform to what is expected by the `StaxEventItemReader` or write a custom reader.

Comment: My goal is to read all `Txn` fragments.I need to read header and footer only once i.e. for validating the records are correct or not.  When i tried to read `Txn` only, batch processing worked perfect. Is ther any way to read this header and footer separate, something like `StaxWriterCallback` ?

Comment: The reader is forward only, if you need the footer to validate the first item in the file, then it is not possible. To keep it simple, I would prepare the data needed for item validation in a separate step and share this info with the chunk-oriented step that reads the XML file.

Comment: If i need footer only after reading all `Txn`, then is it possible with the same itemReader? or i need to write a separate step?